# How to make IP traffic fowarding for Docker user-defined networks permanent?

Tags: docker, routes, iptables

When creating a user-defined Docker bridged network (using `docker network create myname -d bridge`), containers connected to this network may not be able to communicate with the outside world unless IP traffic fowarding is enabled on the Docker host using

```
$ sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
$ sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

as explained in [Enable forwarding from Docker containers to the outside world](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/#enable-forwarding-from-docker-containers-to-the-outside-world)

However, the docs also state

> These settings do not persist across a reboot, so you may need to add them to a start-up script.

but do not explain how to do this?

I'm running Docker on Ubuntu 22.04.1 server if that matters.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to use iptables make sure to also download `iptables-peristent`. This command helps to keep the iptables rules you created after a reboot.

Make sure you save the rules with the command `iptables-save`. Also, make sure you have enabled `ip forwarding` in the kernel level. Since you are using Ubuntu 22.04.1 I would recommend to use `nftables` instead. The `iptables` command is deprecated.

You can also visit their web site at: https://www.nftables.org/
to read their documentation for more information.